# image_tag points to assets/ in Rails 3 after enabling asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have enabled asset pipeline, but still image_tag is prefixed with "assets" instead of "images". Am I missing something? I have upgraded application from rails 2.3 to 3.2.

Comment: what have you written in image_tag

Comment: image_tag image_path("home.png")

Comment: home.png is in assets/image directory?

Comment: yes, assets/images/home/png

Comment: so your image is displaying ?

Comment: no :(, if I change image_tag image_path("assets/home.png"), then only I would see image.

Comment: in public dir assets folder is present or image folder is present what is your asset configuration? are you working on dev or prod mode

Comment: Have you compiled your assets?

Comment: how can we do that? I'm sorry for silly question. 

And I just ran "bundle exec rake assets:clean" command. will it be helpful?

Comment: when I try to run this command: **rake assets:precompile**, I'm getting following error: **CSS after "...r:alpha(opacity": expected ")", was ": 0);"**

Comment: Your some of css is invalid so first rectify invalid css

Comment: okay, now I could run **"bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production"**, do I need to remove "assets" folder from public dir?

Comment: No so your assset is compiled and placed in asset directory now you cna check

Comment: still getting assets path, I think I have missed some steps